# How to style progress bar correctly?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've done a couple of tests trying to style the progress bar for a game i'm currently developing:

Issue: the problem the inside of the progress bar is a one colour fill and its sticking out of my corners:

[image]

Code:

```
 //PROGRESS BARS STYLE
_progressOne.layer.borderWidth =0.5f;
_progressOne.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.345 green: 0.831 blue: 0.973 alpha: 1]CGColor];
//hieght
[self.progressOne setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 3.0)];
```

The user must see the fill inside the boarders.
How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIProgressView appearance] setProgressTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:175.0/255.0 blue:176.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UIProgressView appearance] setTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.996 green:0.788 blue:0.180 alpha:1.000]];
```